# How to pass query parameters in URL in Salesforce Summer 19 Release?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-apps, release-notes

The requirement was to open a Lightning App page and pass some query parameters in the URL. These query parameters were then used to query data and display in a Lightning component present in the Lightning App.

Till Spring 19, it was working fine. This was the URL format:

```
force.com/lightning/n/Document_Upload?id=0015B00000fS9mzQAC&type=AccountDocument
```

where Document_Upload was the name of the Lightning App and 'id' and 'type' were the query parameters.

In Summer 19, the same URL format doesn't work.

In fact, any query parameter appended to a page is removed as the page loads.

So, this URL,

```
force.com/lightning/n/Document_Upload?id=0015B00000fS9mzQAC&type=AccountDocument
```

becomes

```
force.com/lightning/n/Document_Upload
```

How do I pass query parameters here?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I think there is a Critical Update that gets auto-enabled for Summer '19, that forces Lightning URL parameters to be namespaced. And the default namespace for orgs is "c".

So if you add `?foo=bar` to the URL, it will get auto-stripped.

But if you add `?c__foo=bar` to the URL, it will persist.

Comment: Welcome. I'm guessing one reason for this is, SF would like to reserve the right to introduce more standard URL parameters in Lightning, without the chance of subscriber interference.

Comment: @CharlesT: This was helpful workaround. But I was wondering which critical updates talk about this change. 
https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_cruc.htm?edition=&impact=

Comment: There is a link which talks about this update : https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_forcecom_general_namespace_prefix_cruc_reminder.htm

Answer (score 2):

Here is the [Salesforce critical update](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_forcecom_general_namespace_prefix_cruc_reminder.htm) that talks about this.

Comment: Please put the relevant part of this information here, in your answer.